# Laravel update password passes validation but doesn't update record

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, passwords, eloquent

Hi I am using Laravel and I am using a couple of packages for user auth and roles which are [Zizaco Confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide) and I want to update the users password firstly they should input there current password a new password and confirm the password and they should match. Now the validation works but the users password isn't updated in the database. My code is below:

```
public function updatePassword($id) {

     $rules = array(
        'now_password'          => 'required',
        'password'              => 'min:5|confirmed|different:now_password',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required_with:password|min:5'
        );
        //password update.
        $now_password       = Input::get('now_password');
        $password           = Input::get('password');
        $passwordconf       = Input::get('password_confirmation');

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::only('now_password', 'password', 'password_confirmation'), $rules);                  

      if ($validator->fails()) {    
                return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
            }
        elseif (Hash::check($now_password, Auth::user()->password)) {

                    $user = User::find($id);
                    $user->password = Hash::make($password);
                    $user->save();
          return Redirect::back()->with('success', true)->with('message','User updated.');

            } else  {
                return Redirect::back()->withErrors('Password incorrect');
            }


}
```

Any ideas why the users password is not isn't updated using this block of code

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->password = Hash::make($password);
$user->save();
```

### User Model

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;
use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUserInterface;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;

class User extends Eloquent implements ConfideUserInterface
{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    use ConfideUser;
    use HasRole;

    protected $softDelete = true;

    public function favourites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Favourite');
    }


}
```

Comment: Its good logic but you have way TOO MUCH going on in the controller function. You should extract that logic out into say a repository or service provider.

Comment: Are you using a standard User model - or something different? Is there any validation or mutators in there? Perhaps post your User model...

Comment: And how do you know the password is not been updated?

Comment: Im using the confide model and because i logged out and tried new password but it failed tried old one and it worked. Tried multiple times.

Comment: Doesn't confide provide a method for updating password?

Comment: Do the other fields get updated?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk it has a password reset facility, but not an update password.

Comment: @HosseinJabbari no other fields get updated. I checked the updated_at timestamp and this wasn't over written

Comment: Maybei $id is not the value that  you are expecting? Perhaps this function is called with wrong $id param

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check inputted password:

**1.**

```
 $now_password  = Input::get('now_password');
 $user = DB::table('users')->where('name', Auth::user()->name)->first();
        if(Hash::check($now_password, $user->password)){
    //Your update here
}
```

**2.**

```
$now_password   = Input::get('now_password');
if(Hash::check($now_password, Auth::user()->password)){
    //Your update here
}
```

To check if they match and if the new password is different than old.

```
$rules = array(
        'now_password'          => 'required|min:8',
        'password'              => 'required|min:8|confirmed|different:now_password',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:8',
    );
```

And edit your form to (or enter your names):

```
{{ Form::label('now_password', 'Old Password') }}
{{ Form::password('now_password')}}
{{ Form::label('password', 'New Password') }}
{{ Form::password('password')}}
{{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confrim New Password') }}
{{ Form::password('password_confirmation')}}
```

**Update**

Ok, so you don't want to edit only passwords.

Edit your rules:

```
$rules = array(
'now_password'          => 'required|min:5',
'password'              => 'min:5|confirmed|different:now_password',
'password_confirmation' => 'required_with:password|min:5'
);
```

I think that current password should be required in every type of change. Other inputs imo shouldn't be required, because you don't know which data user want to edit.

You should also add to your rules something like:

```
'username'  => alpha_num|unique:users,username
```

etc.. (for more see http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#available-validation-rules)

If Validator pass, you should check which data user want to change (which inputs are not empty).
Something like:

```
if(!empty(Input::get('firstname'))){
    $user->firstname    = Input::get('firstname');
}
```

etc...with every input.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an edit using your example as its not working for me

Comment: thanks. the validation side is working, however the password isn't actually been updated and the success message is displayed. I am updating as so:  `$user = User::find($id); $user->password = Hash::make($password); $user->save();` any ideas? I've updated my question with the new function

Comment: Check if the 'pure update' will work - `DB::table('users')->where('id', User::find($id))->update(array('password' => Hash::make($password))); `Maybe is something wrong with yuor model and then we will go deeper...

Comment: no this didn't work either. any suggestions? In terms of the model I'm using https://github.com/Zizaco/confide package for this. I have a function that updates the username and email field so its strange the password won't update

Comment: Can you show us your $guarded and $fillable arrays from your User model?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: when I dump out $user->save it returns false e.g dd($user->save()); returns bool(false)

Comment: Do you have `app/models/User.php` ?

Comment: Ok. I checked this package documentation and there is an information how to seed something to user table. Ctrl + F -> Seeding.`To seed your users table you should fill also the password_confirmation and confirmation_code fields.` So probably you need to add this variables to your code too.

Comment: there is no `password_confirmation` field but I do how a `confirmation_code` field. what should I do to fill this field in the db?

Comment: this did the trick `$user->password_confirmation = Input::get('password_confirmation');`

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
public function updatePassword($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    User::$rules['now_password'] = 'required';
    // other rules here

    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), User::rules('update', $id));

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    array_forget($data, 'password_confirmation');
    array_forget($data, 'now_password');

    $data['password'] = Hash::make($data['password']);

    $user->update($data);

    return Redirect::back()->with('success', true)->with('message','User updated.');
}
```

Comment: I get an error `Access to undeclared static property: User::$rules`

Answer (score 0):

remember your password confirmation field name must be "password_confirmation" if you used first way...
if you used another name for password confirm field you can use second way.

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'email'    => 'required|unique:user|email|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|max:20',
            'password' => 'required|min:3|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required|in:m,f',
        ]);

$this->validate($request, [
            'email'    => 'required|unique:user|email|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|max:20',
            'password' => 'required|min:3',
            'confirm_password' => 'same:password',
            'gender' => 'required|in:m,f',
        ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function change_password_post($id)
    {
        $rules = array(
                    'current'       =>  'required|string|min:8',
                    'new'       =>  'required|string|min:8',
                    'confirm'       =>  'required|same:new'
                    );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::only('current', 'new', 'confirm'), $rules);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($validator);
        }
else
            {
                $users = User::where('id', '=', $id)->first();

                if (Hash::check(Input::get('current'), $users->password))
                {
                    if(Input::get('new') == Input::get('confirm'))
                    {
                        $users->password =Hash::make(Input::get('new'));
                        $users->save();

                        $msg = array('msg' => 'Password changed Successfully');

                        return Redirect::back()
                            ->withErrors($msg);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $msg = array('msg' => 'New password and Confirm password did not match');

                        return Redirect::back()
                                ->withErrors($msg);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $msg = array('msg' => 'Current password is incorrect');

                    return Redirect::back()
                        ->withErrors($msg);
                }
        }
    }
```