# Laravel user management in Admin Dashboard

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

i building a user management page in my dashboard so admin can create and update user information from the dashboard...

but, i have no clue to create update and create method especially when we talk about password because it must be Hashed!!

is there any idea to do this??

User Table

> Name - email - password - avatar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually register a user in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753951/manually-register-a-user-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You need different parts in your application to provide this functionality:

- Routes
- Methods in Controller (Display template with form, Handle submit of form)
- View (Your layout and the form and input elements itself)

In the action handling form request you will need to hash the password. This can be archived using the Hash-Fascade (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/hashing#basic-usage).

Example implementation: https://www.5balloons.info/setting-up-change-password-with-laravel-authentication/ (be aware of using Hash::make in newer Laravel versions instead of bcrypt)

There is also an alternative approach I've not tested yet: [laravel 5,update User password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708916/laravel-5-update-user-password)

Just as hint, if you are working on a Non-Commercial/Hobby project maybe you are interested in trying the Laravel Admin Builder which then is also free: https://backpackforlaravel.com/

Edit:

- The tutorial is missing usage of the Laravel provided CSRF-Protection. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#forms)
- It would be also more elegant to use Form Requests for basic validation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation)

Answer (score 0):

You can hash the password like so:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

// ...

Hash::make($data['password'])
```